# Sharepoint 2007 Production Server, can't authenticate against my site

Tags: authentication

If I visit the address:

http://localhost:8260 I can browse my site without any problems.

If I try http://machineName:8260 I get prompted to login, and my credentials don't work.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually edited the host in IIS to include the fully qualified name of the machine, then restarted IIS, and now can access the site using machineName.domain:port.